# Number of elements in $\{ \{ \{\}\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand $\{\}$ is an empty set so has no elements, $\{\{\}\}$ is the same as $\{\emptyset\}$ so has $1$ element.

But what does $\{ \{ \{\}\}\}$ mean and how many elements may it contain?

Comment: $\{ \{ \{ \} \} \}$ is a set that contains (remove outer brackets) a single element $\{ \{  \} \}$ that in turn contains (remove again outer brackets) a single element $\{  \}$ that in turn contains (remove again outer brackets) ... nothing.

Comment: So it contains 2 elements?

Comment: "is a set that contains (remove outer brackets) a single element" What is not clear in my wording ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA OP can't handle deep recursion, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

Only look at the outermost braces. $\{\{\{\}\}\}$ is a set with one element $\{\{\}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It has $1$ element. And other examples:
$$
\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}
\lbrace \lbrace\phi \rbrace , \lbrace\rbrace\rbrace & \text{has 2 elements} \\
\lbrace \lbrace \lbrace\phi \rbrace , \lbrace\rbrace\rbrace \rbrace &\text{has 1 element } \\
\lbrace \phi ,\lbrace \rbrace\rbrace & \text{has 1 element}\\
\lbrace \lbrace \phi ,\lbrace \rbrace\rbrace \rbrace &  \text{has 1 element} \\
\lbrace \lbrace\phi \rbrace , \lbrace\lbrace\rbrace\rbrace \rbrace & \text{has 1 element}
\end{array}\right.
$$